# Java SOAP client using SOAP UI library and WSDL file

Tags: java, soap, wsdl, soapui

I'm trying to build a Java based SOAP client which imports a WSDL file and sends a request to the end point specified in the WSDL.  I'm currently using the SOAP UI library and while it can compile, it is connecting to the wrong endpoint.  In addition, I'm not sure where/how I define the authentication credentials (user/pass).

I am using a base code found on this site but this doesn't include authentication. It is also getting the endpoint from the wrong attribute when I run the code.  Please help!

```
package com.bbog.soap;

import com.eviware.soapui.impl.wsdl.WsdlInterface;
import com.eviware.soapui.impl.wsdl.WsdlOperation;
import com.eviware.soapui.impl.wsdl.WsdlProject;
import com.eviware.soapui.impl.wsdl.support.wsdl.WsdlImporter;
import com.eviware.soapui.model.iface.Operation;

public class WsdlAnalyzer {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        WsdlProject project = new WsdlProject();
        WsdlInterface[] wsdls = WsdlImporter.importWsdl(project, "file:/home/asarkar/Documents/EthocaAlerts-Sandbox.wsdl");
        WsdlInterface wsdl = wsdls[0];
        for (Operation operation : wsdl.getOperationList()) {
            WsdlOperation op = (WsdlOperation) operation;
            System.out.println("OP:"+op.getName());
            System.out.println(op.createRequest(true));
            System.out.println("Response:");
            System.out.println(op.createResponse(true));
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: How about using `wsimport`?

Comment: Do you want to do this in Java (and more appropriate libraries), or in SoapUI? Mixing the two will lead to problems, such as what you describe. Pick one!

Comment: I think I'm creating more problems using SoapUI so I can try doing it in Java.  Could someone help point me in the right direction to get it set up please, thanks!